# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException Thrown

Tags: java, indexing, parameters, substring

sorry if the question has been already asked, i just got a `"java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"` thrown though my program was running correctly at the first try. I have tried to change the index of my substring but it's not working either. here's the full exception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 8, end 17, length 9
at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
at platerecognition.PlateRecognition.main(PlateRecognition.java:31)
```

and here's the lines:

```
public class Asserv {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

   final File folder = new File("./Verr");

   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("Gel.csv"));

   for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) { 
        String filename = fileEntry.getName();
        String date = filename.substring(0, 8);
        System.out.println(date);
        String time = filename.substring(8,17);
        System.out.println(time);
        int index = filename.indexOf("_", 19);
        String plate = filename.substring(18,index);
        System.out.println(plate);        
        int index2 = filename.indexOf("-", index+2);
        String cam = filename.substring(index+4, index2);
        System.out.println(cam);
        String last = filename.substring(index2 + 1, filename.indexOf('.', index2 + 1));
        System.out.println(last);
        System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
```

Comment: What is the value of `filename` ?

Comment: can you post the value of time ?

Comment: Your end index must be <= your String's length

Comment: Please put code into the question rather than into comments - and show the *actual value* rather than just the code which creates the value.

Comment: sorry, it's done now

Comment: Now show the value of `filename` where this break to be a [mcve].

Comment: I don't think i understand what you mean by the "value" of the filename

Comment: Adding the folder name doesn't give me the result of `listFiles()` so I can't confirm my answer. Please provde a [mcve] using a `String[]` with one working value and one failing value. Simply print `filename` in the beginning of the loop and take the last two printed value.

Comment: Well, i have changed the value of String time to "nix", and doing so gives me the following exception after the run: Begin 18, end -1, length 9

Answer (score 2):

You can read the exception message `begin 8, end 17, length 9` like the following :

*You asked for a `substring` from 8(begin) to 17(end) but the current length is 9.*

From [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-)

> Throws:
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or **endIndex is larger than the length of this String object**, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

You need to check the length of the `String` to prevent this exception. Something like :

```
int begin = 8;
int end = 17;
s.substring(begin, Math.min(s.length(), end));
```

I used `Math.min(s.length(), end)` to get the lowest value, it will be either the `end` or the limit of this `String`.

Note: This would be the same problem if `begin` is larger than `end` (or the length). So this is not fully safe but you get the idea.

Here is a quick method

```
public static String substring(String s, int begin, int end){
    //Prevent out of bounds by stopping at the end of the `String`
    end = Math.min(end, s.length());

    return s.substring(begin, end);
}
```

Comment: the substring from 8 to 17 has exactly a length of 9 so i don't think that it goes too far

Comment: I believe `length` is the length of the `String` on which you call `substring`, not the length of the substring itself. I have to guess since this message depends on the JDK used. But the documentation from `String.substring` is quite explicit.

Comment: the length of the string from which i call the substring is 20, which is not too far also, what i don't understand too is that the program worked correctly at first try

Comment: What do you mean with "_first try_" @YacineWalid ?

Comment: I mean the first time i made the run

Comment: Provide a [mcve] @YacineWalid, this include the data on which the process throw the exception. The explanation I gave is the only one i see. I don't understand what you mean by "_the first time i made the run_" since I don't know what you have ran exactly.

Comment: okey done ! you can check and tell me if you need more

Comment: Can i ask also about why i get the (Unknown Source) error ?

Comment: Hello everyone ! the source of the problem was the JDK version as i was working first on 1.7 (oldest) and i updated to 9.0 ! Thank you all for your answers

Comment: @YacineWalid. What unknown source .... be specific, we are not in your mind. About the "solution", `substring` documentation didn't changed in Java 9 so you will get an exception too. I would guess this was your `File` that was incorrect but since you never provide a [mcve] I can't confirm. All I can say is that `substring` in java 7 work the same as Java 8 and from what I see Java 9.

Comment: Hello @AxelH, i am really sorry, i understand what you asking me but i couldn't answer you in the proper way, maybe if you have time we can start a private chat and get in deep of the problem, anyway, since i updated to JDK 9.0 no exception is thrown and the program is running correctly with a coverage of 99%